# Update database after returning a php page

Tags: php

I have what seems to be a complicated problem.

I need to query one database for a list, this list contains article ID#'s. As soon as I get the list, I will then build a page that contains the articles from that list.

The articles themselves are in a different database. Once the page is built and sent to the user, I need to send a list of the article ID#'s used to a third database. I don't want the visitor to have to wait for the I'd#'s to be processed before sending them the page.

What I want to know is how to send the page and then the update. The updates have to happen in real time or close to it.

To clarify, to produce the page I will need to query two different databases. Once the page is produced and served to the visitor, I will need to send the results from the first query to a third database.

This last step of updating the third database will have nothing to do with creating the page, but it needs to be done while the results from the first query is available. I just would like to return the page as soon as it is ready without waiting for the update operation to complete.

Comment: sounds like a job for ajax perhaps...not sure I even understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four ideas:

1. Write a command line PHP script to do the logging operation which takes the ids on the command line, and then start a background job from PHP to run it, using exec or one of the similar functions

   $ids = implode(" ", $arrayofids);

   exec("/usr/bin/php5 /path/to/your/script.php {$ids} &");

   where the key thing is the ampersand on the end to run the job in the background. Your path to php may be different.
2. Similar to that, rather than command line PHP you could command line a cURL call in the background to a page which does the database write. That means the write is still taking place in the context of the web server, which sometimes makes permissions and including the right files easier. With an appropriate test or htaccess file you can prevent anyone other than the same machine accessing such pages if it's important. Again the key thing is to start it in the background so the page doesn't need to wait.
3. Somewhat similar to 1: have a daemon running continuously (it could also be written in PHP and started on boot, e.g. with cron) which picks up the ids from a queue and does what it needs with them. Your queue could be a folder of files to process and the web page script writes the files (using a unique name, there's a PHP function to do get such filenames), and the daemon scans the directory every few seconds/minutes/whatever and consumes them. You have to write the files, of course, so that may not be much quicker than writing them into the third database in the first place, though that's the case more-or-less whatever you do.
4. If you don't mind exposing the URL of web page which writes to the third database you could write the user's page with a little Javascript at the end (after the </body>) which makes a request on that URL which posts to the third database. That means the third part comes from the user's browser not the server. You'd have to be prepared for some spam calls if you do this, but it's essentially how Google Analytics works, for example. Unless it's a huge list, the ids can be parameters in the URL; if it is big, they can be POSTed back. Either way it'll be an Ajax call, so jQuery makes this easier to write than doing it for yourself.